# Windows Server 2022: Can't add AzureAD user to Remotedesktopuser group

Tags: windows, server, azure-active-directory, windows-server-2022

I want to setup RDP authentication using Yubikeys.

According to the guide (https://swjm.blog/the-complete-guide-to-rdp-with-yubikeys-fido2-cba-1bfc50f39b43) this should be fairly easy.

But I fail when trying to run the command
`LocalGroupMember -Group "Remotedesktopbenutzer" -Member "AzureAD\lars.kusch@stbk.link"`

```
LocalGroupMember : Der Prinzipal AzureAD\lars.kusch@stbk.link wurde nicht gefunden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ LocalGroupMember -Group "Remotedesktopbenutzer" -Member "AzureAD\lars ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AzureAD\lars.kusch@stbk.link:String) [Get-LocalGroupMember], PrincipalN
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PrincipalNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand
```

The host is Azure-AD-Hybrid-joined:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

             AzureAdJoined : YES
          EnterpriseJoined : NO
              DomainJoined : YES
                DomainName : STBK
               Device Name : vrdp501172.stbk.link

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device Details                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                  DeviceId : XXX
                Thumbprint : XXX
 DeviceCertificateValidity : [ 2023-07-11 10:27:44.000 UTC -- 2033-07-11 10:57:44.000 UTC ]
            KeyContainerId : XXX
               KeyProvider : Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
              TpmProtected : NO
          DeviceAuthStatus : SUCCESS

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tenant Details                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                TenantName : Steuerberater Kusch
                  TenantId : c742fd56-3458-40a8-8c97-7a57e83fecb3
               AuthCodeUrl : https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/authorize
            AccessTokenUrl : https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/token
                    MdmUrl : https://enrollment.manage.microsoft.com/enrollmentserver/discovery.svc
                 MdmTouUrl : https://portal.manage.microsoft.com/TermsofUse.aspx
          MdmComplianceUrl : https://portal.manage.microsoft.com/?portalAction=Compliance
               SettingsUrl :
            JoinSrvVersion : 2.0
                JoinSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/EnrollmentServer/device/
                 JoinSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
             KeySrvVersion : 1.0
                 KeySrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/EnrollmentServer/key/
                  KeySrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
        WebAuthNSrvVersion : 1.0
            WebAuthNSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/webauthn/XXX/
             WebAuthNSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net
    DeviceManagementSrvVer : 1.0
    DeviceManagementSrvUrl : https://enterpriseregistration.windows.net/manage/XXX/
     DeviceManagementSrvId : urn:ms-drs:enterpriseregistration.windows.net

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User State                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                    NgcSet : NO
           WorkplaceJoined : NO
             WamDefaultSet : YES
       WamDefaultAuthority : organizations
              WamDefaultId : https://login.microsoft.com
            WamDefaultGUID : {XXX} (AzureAd)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SSO State                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                AzureAdPrt : YES
      AzureAdPrtUpdateTime : 2023-07-13 06:19:37.000 UTC
      AzureAdPrtExpiryTime : 2023-07-27 06:19:36.000 UTC
       AzureAdPrtAuthority : https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX
             EnterprisePrt : NO
    EnterprisePrtAuthority :
                 OnPremTgt : NO
                  CloudTgt : YES
         KerbTopLevelNames : .windows.net,.windows.net:1433,.windows.net:3342,.azure.net,.azure.net:1433,.azure.net:3342

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Diagnostic Data                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

        AadRecoveryEnabled : NO
    Executing Account Name : STBK\lars.kusch, lars.kusch@stbk.link
               KeySignTest : PASSED

        DisplayNameUpdated : YES
          OsVersionUpdated : YES
           HostNameUpdated : YES

      Last HostName Update : NONE

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IE Proxy Config for Current User                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

      Auto Detect Settings : YES
    Auto-Configuration URL :
         Proxy Server List :
         Proxy Bypass List :

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| WinHttp Default Proxy Config                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

               Access Type : DIRECT

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ngc Prerequisite Check                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

            IsDeviceJoined : YES
             IsUserAzureAD : YES
             PolicyEnabled : NO
          PostLogonEnabled : YES
            DeviceEligible : NO
        SessionIsNotRemote : NO
            CertEnrollment : none
              PreReqResult : WillNotProvision

For more information, please visit https://www.microsoft.com/aadjerrors
```

Has anyone an idea, why this fails and therefore remote RDP connection fails?

Kind regards,

Lars Kusch